# Transforming TRestResponse content to TFDJSONDataSets

Tags: rest, delphi, rest-client

I am using delphi XE7, and I need help to transform `TRestResponse` content to `TFDJSONDataSets` on the client side of a Rest Client application.

In the code posted below I need a function in this line:

```
LDataSets := function(sContent)-->transform sContent to TFDJSONDataSets
```

How can I do this?

```
//client side
procedure TaskComplete;
var sContent:string;
LDataSets: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  sContent:=ModuloCliente.RESTResponse1.content;
  LDataSets := function(sContent)-->Here I need to transform sContent to TFDJSONDataSets
  //Prepare temp MemoryTable 
  memTable.Active := False;
  memTable.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(LDataSets, 0));
end;

//request to rest server
procedure DoRequest;
begin
  ModuloCliente.RESTClient1.BaseURL:='http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TsrvServerMetodos';
  ModuloCliente.RESTRequest1.Resource:='"pending_msg_to_user_token"/{param1}';
  ModuloCliente.RESTRequest1.Params.ParameterByName('param1').Value:='1';
  ModuloCliente.RESTRequest1.ExecuteAsync(TaskComplete,true,true);
end;

//server side
function TSrvServerMetodos.pending_msg_to_user_token(qry:string): TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  qryStaff.Active := False;
  with  qryStaff do begin
    Params.Clear;
    SQL.Clear;
    unprepare;
    SQL.Add(qry);
  end;
  Result := TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, qryStaff);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TaskComplete;
var 
  sContent:string;
  LDataSets: TFDJSONDataSets;
  oJsonObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  oJsonObject: ModuloCliente.RESTResponse1.Response.JSONValue as TJSONObject;

  LDataSets:= TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  TFDJSONInterceptor.JSONObjectToDataSets(oJsonObject, LDataSets);

  //Prepare temp MemoryTable 
  memTable.Active := False;
  memTable.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(LDataSets, 0));
end;
```